# Bootstrap grid 3 items that each take up 33%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap's grid system. I got three columns, each col-XX-4 and every second pixel that I rezise the window with the three elements wind up a fraction of a pixel smaller than the 100% available width (930px in this case). The reason this is disturbing is because the above element is a Bootstrap carousel, 100% width that works flawlessly, always stays 930px.

Here's what I mean (I've zoomed in quite a bit):

[image]

Here's a zoomed out picture:

[image: Image2]

The HTML code I use is:

```
<!-- Puffs Start -->
<div class="row">
  <?php if (have_rows('puffs')):
          $iterations = 0;
          while(have_rows('puffs')): the_row();
            $iterations++;
            $headline = get_sub_field('headline');
            $text = get_sub_field('text');
            $link = get_sub_field('link');
  ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <?php if($iterations == 2): ?>
                <div class="puff second">
              <?php else: ?>
                <div class="puff">
              <?php endif; ?>
              <h3 class="puffHeadline"><?php echo $headline; ?></h3>
              <p class="puffText"><?php echo $text; ?> </p>
              <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                <img class="puffArrow" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/arrow.jpg'; ?>">
              </a>
              </div>
            </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- Puffs End -->
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
.puff {
  height:190px;
  background:#85bf61;
  padding:20px 20px 0 20px;
}

.puff.second {
  background:#acd373;
}

.puffHeadline {
  font-size:33px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  font-weight:400;
}

.puffText {
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:300;
}

.puffArrow {
  background:url(../img/arrow.jpg);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

This is an image of Chrome's Dev Console for the `<div class="col-xx-4></div>` elements

[image: Chrome dev tools]

So, the math is correct here, 310px times 3 equals to 930px, but the issue here is that every 2nd "pixel" resize of my browser, the width of each element equals to 309.984px.

Live preview: http://rbmedia.se/gfx/avesina/

I hope I made myself clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the complete CSS. We don't know the values of other elements which could be conflicting.

Comment: Added the CSS for those elements, there are no surrounding elements though, these are the only ones inside the row. Otherwise you can check it live at http://rbmedia.se/gfx/avesina/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to sub-pixel sizing. There is a lot of discussion on the topic.

- http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/17/sub-pixel-rendering-and-the-css-object-model.aspx
- http://maxlapides.com/fixing-subpixel-layout-rendering-in-safari/

If you want to be more depressed, look at it in Safari. It translates 309.984px to 309px (it just drops the decimal) so your row is actually 3px too narrow instead of just 1.

In other words, it is a browser-specific issue.

The easiest thing to do in your case is to just set a `background-color` on the `.row`, which will color that remaining couple pixels on the right.

HTML (add a class to the row)

```
<div class="row puffs">
```

CSS (color the row to match the last of the 3 `col`s)

```
.row.puffs {
    background-color: #85bf61;
}
```